# No such cookbook exception in Chef even if cookbook is available and dependency is set - AWS OpsWorks

Tags: amazon-web-services, chef-infra, devops, aws-opsworks

I am a beginner in Chef and AWS OpsWorks. I was trying to experiment with custom recipes. I created a git repository having a directory `test_cookbook`, and configured chef to get cookbooks from it. Inside that, I created files like below;

```
test_cookbook
  |_metadata.rb
  |_recipes
    |_testrecipe.rb
```

below is the content of `metadata.rb`

```
depends 'magic_shell'
```

magic_shell is an open cookbook and is available in chef supermarket https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/magic_shell

While I try to execute the `testrecipe`, I am getting below error;

```
[2021-01-12T09:52:23+00:00] INFO: HTTP Request Returned 412 Precondition Failed: No such cookbook: magic_shell
 
================================================================================
Error Resolving Cookbooks for Run List:
================================================================================
 
 
Missing Cookbooks:
------------------
No such cookbook: magic_shell
```

Can somebody tell me why this is happening and how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The dependency is not packaged.

As per the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/opsworks/latest/userguide/best-practices-packaging-cookbooks-locally.html)

> You can use Berkshelf to package your cookbook dependencies locally, upload the package to Amazon S3, and modify your stack to use the package on Amazon S3 as a cookbook source.

OR pull the dependency using Berksfile and push them to your git source.

For example, I have a dependency for **opsworks_helpers** in *metadata.rb*

```
 $ grep depends metadata.rb
 depends   'opsworks_helpers'
```

and my current directory structure is like this

```
    $ tree
    .
    ├── collectd
    ..
    │   │   └── collectd.rb
    │   ├── metadata.rb

    └── opsworks_helpers
        ├── Berksfile
        ├── CHANGELOG.md
        ├── Gemfile
    ...
                    └── serverspec
                        └── spec_helper.rb
```